# Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop. Passing parameters with context API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-context

I am using React context to get the login function and error which is defined in the context provider file to login in into the firebase database, and use the thrown error in login to display it in the app.

My problem is I didn't get any error when I just use the error thrown from the firebase auth to display the error in the app, but I also added other errors like empty fields to also show an error field in the app.

After doing that I get this too many re-renders error. I think this error is due to using multiple if statements in the function. Can you please suggest a new option or if this is wrong explain please.

**Context Provider file**

```
import React from 'react';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

export const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = React.useState('');

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        user,
        setUser,
        error,
        login: async (email, pwd) => {
          try {
            await auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pwd);
          } catch (e) {
            setError(e);
          }
        },
        register: async (email, pwd) => {
          try {
            await auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pwd);
          } catch (e) {
            setError(e);
          }
        },
        logout: async () => {
          try {
            await auth().signOut();
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
          }
        },
      }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

**App file**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Button, Image, Text, TouchableOpacity, View} from 'react-native';
import styles from '../styles/Styles';
import FormInput from '../components/FormInput';
import FormButton from '../components/FormButton';
import SocialButton from '../components/SocialButton';
import {AuthContext} from '../navigation/AuthProvider';
import ErrorText from '../components/ErrorText';

const LoginScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState('');

  const {login, error} = React.useContext(AuthContext);
  const [errorForwarded, setErrorForwarded] = React.useState(null);

  if (error) {
    setErrorForwarded(error);
  }

  if (!email || !password) {
    setErrorForwarded('fields-empty');
  }

  const renderErrorText = e => {
    if (e.code === 'auth/invalid-email') {
      return <ErrorText errorText="Email invalid!" />;
    }
    if (e.code === 'auth/user-not-found') {
      return <ErrorText errorText="User not found!" />;
    }
    if (e.code === 'auth/wrong-password') {
      return <ErrorText errorText="Wrong password!" />;
    }
    if (e === 'fields-empty') {
      return <ErrorText errorText="Fields cannot be empty!" />;
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.loginContainer}>
      <Image
        source={require('../assets/rn-social-logo.png')}
        style={styles.loginLogo}
      />
      <Text style={styles.loginText}>Sign In</Text>
      <FormInput
        labelValue={email}
        onChangeText={email => setEmail(email)}
        placeholderText="Email"
        iconType="user"
        keyboardType="email-address"
        autoCapitalize="none"
        autoCorrect={false}
      />
      <FormInput
        labelValue={password}
        onChangeText={pwd => setPassword(pwd)}
        placeholderText="Password"
        iconType="lock"
        secureTextEntry={true}
      />
      {error ? renderErrorText(errorForwarded) : null}
      <FormButton
        buttonTitle="Sign In"
        onPress={() => {
          {
            email && password ? login(email, password) : {};
          }
        }}
      />
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginForgetBtn}>
        <Text style={styles.loginNavBtnText}>Forgot Password?</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <SocialButton
        buttonTitle="Sign In with Facebook"
        buttonType="facebook-square"
        color="#4867aa"
        backgroundColor="#e6eaf4"
      />
      <SocialButton
        buttonTitle="Sign In with Google"
        buttonType="google"
        color="#de4d41"
        backgroundColor="#f5e7ea"
      />
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.loginForgetBtn}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Signup')}>
        <Text style={styles.loginNavBtnText}>
          Don't have an account? Create here...
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

export default LoginScreen;
```

Comment: Put your `if (error)` and `if (!email || !password)` statements in `useEffects`, also change the `{error ? ...}` statement (inside render) to `{errorForwarded ? ...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you are coming across multiple rerenders have nothing to do with the if condition in your function. By running the functions to set the state directly within the component's function, you are forcing a rerender, after which it starts to run the function from top to bottom, where it again sets the state.

Only react hooks are not reinitialized/run and can be prevented from running on every subsequent rerender, so you will need to use the `useEffect()` hook with an array of dependencies to watch, so that you don't run into unnecessary state changes on rerenders.

I'm going to include changes for the relevant bits of the code(before the return statement on App component)

```
const [email, setEmail] = React.useState('');
const [password, setPassword] = React.useState('');

const {login, error} = React.useContext(AuthContext);
const [errorForwarded, setErrorForwarded] = React.useState(null);

React.useEffect(() => {
  if (error) {
    setErrorForwarded(error);
  }
}, [error]) //using an array of dependencies like this ensures that the function only runs on changes in the error state

React.useEffect(() => {
  if (!email || !password) {
    setErrorForwarded('fields-empty');
  }
}, [email, password]) //similarly, only run this hook for changes in email or password
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, I knew the problem that causes the re-render was that multiple if statements directly in the function component, I just couldn't figure out how to overcome that.

It worked when I use a function to check those if conditions to set those state and call that function in button submit before calling the API. But I think useEffect hook does it much better, Thank you all in clarifying me.

Can I clarify something else, say at first error variable is empty so errorForwarded will be set to empty. Now on the re-render again errorForwarded will be set to empty. So my question is even state change is detected the actual state value hasn't changed. Then why re-render occurrs. Thanks.